# Cannot close angular material sidenav by clicking on backdrop in IOS

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following implementation of angular material sidenav. I can close the sidenav by hitting its background in desktop and Android. But the sidenav doesn't close in IOS. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>

  <mat-sidenav 
    #leftSideNav 
    [disableClose]="false" 
    [mode]="getDashboardSideNavMode()" 
    [opened]="isDesktop()" 
    [position]="'start'" 
    [fixedInViewport]="isDesktop()" 
    id="matDashboardSidenav" 
    (open)="addNoScrollBackground()" 
    (close)="removeNoScrollBackground()">
    <wab-dashboard-side-nav></wab-dashboard-side-nav>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content [ngClass]="{'noscroll': isMenuOpen}">
    //main content goes here
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```